# How do I bind the value on the button to my ng-model?

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, ionic-framework

I am trying to bind the value on the button to my `ng-model`, but it doesn't seem to work. Does anyone have any suggestions on what I should do?

I am using the datepicker from https://github.com/rajeshwarpatlolla/ionic-datepicker

```
<div class="col">
  <label class="item item-input small">
   Start Date: <br> 

    <ionic-datepicker input-obj="datepickerObject">        
      <input type="button" ng-model="vm.newObject.startDate" value="
        {{datepickerObject.inputDate|date:'dd - MMM - yy'}}"> 
    </ionic-datepicker>

   </label>
</div>
```

Comment: why you need `ng-model` on a button?

Comment: According to the angularjs documentation, ng-model seems to work only with select, input and textarea. I am not sure if there are any other ways to bind the data. Please enlighten me

Comment: ng-model is used in order to populate the model with what the user enters or selects in a field, and vice-versa. You don't enter or select anything with a button. You click on it, and can react to the click using ng-click. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is this create a mini event scheduler. So upon clicking the datepicker button and choosing a date, I would like to save this data into my newly created object (newObject) as the starting date.

Comment: You can use callback, and set the scope property as described in [readme](https://github.com/rajeshwarpatlolla/ionic-datepicker). It doesn't make sense to bind the value on button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `ng-model` from the `button` and you can modify your `datepickerObject` object like this:

```
$scope.datepickerObject = {
    // ... Other keys & values
    callback: function(value) {
        $scope.newObject.startDate = value;
        // or use the "vm" variable as you are using (not sure how you are using the scope)
        // vm.newObject.startDate = value; 
    }
};
```

From the documentation link you mentioned:

> r) callback(Mandatory) : This the callback function, which will get
>   the selected date in to the controller. You can define this function
>   as follows.

Answer (score 0):

we can use button element with {{}} to display the data returned

```
<ionic-datepicker input-obj="datepickerObject"> 

    <button type="button">{{datepickerObject.inputDate|date:'dd - MMM - yy'}} 
</button> 

</ionic-datepicker>
```